# How do I insert my function into an array without it being called?

Tags: python, pygame

I have this pygame code which has some functions, I want to be able to put the functions apple1() and apple2() in the list without it being called immediately and then be able to call it from the list.

This is what i tried:

```
 #for all the apple
 def apple1():
   pygame.draw.rect(screen,COLOR.GREEN, [ posR,posU, apblock, apblock])

 def apple2():
   pygame.draw.rect(screen,COLOR.RED, [ posiR,posiU, apblock, apblock])

 def random_apple():
   array = [apple1(),apple2()]
   i = random.randrange(0,1)

   x = array[i]
   return x

 def time_apple():
     while time == True:
        random_apple()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the parentheses from their names.

Also, I think you'll either want to use `randrange(0,2)` or `randint(0,1)`.

```
def random_apple():
   array = [apple1,apple2]
   i = random.randrange(0,2)

   x = array[i]
   return x()
```

Edit:
For a slightly more Pythonic solution, obviating the need for the `random_apple` function, you might consider:

```
# import as needed
import random
import pygame
import time

#for all the apple
def apple1():
  pygame.draw.rect(screen,COLOR.GREEN, [ posR,posU, apblock, apblock])

def apple2():
  pygame.draw.rect(screen,COLOR.RED, [ posiR,posiU, apblock, apblock])

def time_apple():
  while time == True:
    random.choice([apple1, apple2])()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put names of these callables:

```
array = [apple1,apple2]
```

and then change invocation to

```
random_apple()()
```

Comment: Presumably the OP would like to eventually call one of these functions. This would never call either `apple1` or `apple2` without requiring other changes.

Comment: And back and forth we go :)